# Boundary conditions of eigenfunctions of Schrödinger equation with Yukawa potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, potential, schroedinger-equation, boundary-conditions

I was trying to solve the eigenvalues/eigenfunctions problem of the  Schrödinger equation with Yukawa potential
$$V(r)=-\frac{1}{r}\exp \left ({-\frac{r}{r_0}}\right).$$

I worked, as usual in the case of central potentials, using the substitution $R(r)r=y(r)$, introducing the parameter $k=\sqrt{2|E|}$ and the variable $x=2kr$ and then, using $y(x)=C_{nl}x^{l+1}\exp{-\frac{x}{2}}v_l(x)$, I had to solve the equation

$$xv''_l+(2l+2-x)v'_l-\left[l+1+\dfrac{x}{2k^2}V\left(\frac{x}{2k}\right)\right]v_l=0.$$

Now I need boundary conditions, and I thought that they could be the same as in the case of Coulomb potential because for $r\to 0$ the exponential goes to $1$ but I'm not entirely sure.

If I am wrong, do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: I hope I'm wrong but aren't you confounding $r$ and $x$?

Comment: And your third equation could benefit from some parentheses.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I omitted this passage: it is introduced the new variable $x=2kr$ where $k=\sqrt{2|E|}$

Comment: OK. You should very much include that is your question, to avoid downvotes.

Comment: Thank you for the advice!

Comment: Have you done [due diligence](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.5050621)?

Comment: Have you tried applying the boundary conditions you mentioned? If so, did you run into any issues?

Comment: Hi Andrew, I applied the boundary conditions mentioned (including that the wavefunction goes to 0 for $r\to\infty$) and I obtained a discrete spectrum as expected. My only doubt was if the boundary conditions were good